# Is the work required to charge a capacitor the same as the energy stored by the capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work, capacitance

If you have a capacitor and you need to calculate the work required to charge it, would this simply be equal to the energy that the capacitor holds?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Siddhant Kumar! I'm afraid your question is somewhat ambiguous. The answer depends on what "the work" refers to. If it refers to the work done by the source, then the answer is generally no. If it refers to the work done on the (ideal) capacitor, then the answer is yes. Would you clarify your question in this regard?